# Slow PostGIS line intersection even with indexes

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection, linestring, st-intersects

I have line data contained in different graphs. Querying data over multiple graphs and using st_intersects results in slow queries. All lines are represented as `geometry(LineString)`.

I am querying multiple graphs together containing over 3 million lines, the table contains over 5 million lines.

Here is a sample query counting the data. This part of the query is used in more complex queries and is the biggest bottleneck. Following query filters around 63.000 lines from 3 mil.

```
select count(*) from graph_schema.graph_line as gline 
where gline.graph_id in (26, 27) 
and st_intersects(gline.line, st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(1280 0, 0 720)'));
```

I have partial spatial indexes for each graph:

```
CREATE INDEX graph_line_line_idx<GRAPH_ID> ON graph_schema.graph_line USING GIST (line) WHERE graph_schema.graph_line.graph_id = <GRAPH_ID>;
```

And index on the foreign key of the `graph_id`

With this setup, I cannot make PostgreSQL use the spacial indexes when querying multiple graphs. The query takes **18** seconds.

```
Aggregate  (cost=1382969.26..1382969.27 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=18161.980..18161.980 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on graph_line gline  (cost=0.00..1381079.93 rows=755732 width=0) (actual time=35.923..18156.004 rows=63306 loops=1)
"        Filter: ((graph_id = ANY ('{26,27}'::integer[])) AND (line && '0102000000020000000000000000009440000000000000000000000000000000000000000000808640'::geometry) AND _st_intersects(line,     '0102000000020000000000000000009440000000000000000000000000000000000000000000808640'::geometry))"
        Rows Removed by Filter: 4898682
Planning time: 0.686 ms
Execution time: 18162.012 ms
```

So I tried to create an index for this specific query:

```
CREATE INDEX graph_line_line_geom_advanced ON graph_schema.graph_line USING GIST (line) WHERE graph_schema.graph_line.graph_id in (26, 27);
```

This makes PostgreSQL use the index, but the query is still slow - no real speedup.

```
Aggregate  (cost=782285.83..782285.84 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=17892.661..17892.661 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on graph_line gline  (cost=106709.03..780375.43 rows=764159 width=0) (actual time=1109.125..17886.986 rows=63306 loops=1)
"        Recheck Cond: ((line && '0102000000020000000000000000009440000000000000000000000000000000000000000000808640'::geometry) AND (graph_id = ANY ('{26,27}'::integer[])))"
"        Filter: _st_intersects(line, '0102000000020000000000000000009440000000000000000000000000000000000000000000808640'::geometry)"
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3077146
        Heap Blocks: exact=44560
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on graph_line_line_geom_advanced  (cost=0.00..106517.99 rows=2292477 width=0) (actual time=1098.754..1098.754 rows=3140452 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (line && '0102000000020000000000000000009440000000000000000000000000000000000000000000808640'::geometry)
Planning time: 0.693 ms
Execution time: 17893.234 ms
```

I also tried a different approach to query the data, but no difference.

```
select count(*) from graph_schema.graph_line as gline
join (SELECT st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(1280 0, 0 720)') :: geometry AS line2) line2 on st_intersects(gline.line, line2)
where gline.graph_id in (26, 27);
```

Is there any way to greatly improve the query performance? Either by better usage of index, data representation or by preparing the data? Is the slow performance caused by `st_geomfromtext`?
I should also mention that the intersecting line can be changed by the user - so I cannot effectively prepare the data in advance.

Comment: Have you tuned Postgresql for Postgis or are you using it 'out-of-the-box'?  Also have tyou clustered your data?

Comment: I did not tune my postgres in any way - at least I do not think so. Can you please provide some links or docs on how to do that? I do not know how to cluster using partial indexes - is there a way?

Comment: This comes up all the time. It is because ST_GeomFromText appears inside ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) so the index is not used properly. You do not want a bitmap index scan in this context. Put the st_geomfromtext in a subquery or a cte. Something like `WITH line(geom) AS (SELECT st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(1280 0, 0 720)')))
select count(*) from graph_schema.graph_line gline, line l 
where gline.graph_id in (26, 27) 
and st_intersects(gline.line, l.geom)`

Comment: Also, do you have an index on graph_id? Any in not always the most performant way to do array search. You might be better off with one of the gin index op classes, see, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/gin-builtin-opclasses.html#GIN-BUILTIN-OPCLASSES-TABLE

Comment: @JohnPowell Thanks four your advice. I have already tried the subquery and CTE approach. It does not help very much. At this point, it seems it does not even matter if I have an index on graph_id or not. Both result in same query plan - for the graph_id condition.

Comment: ok, sorry that didn't help, sometimes it does. Whether the graph_id or the spatial index get hit first will depend on the specificity of the query as determined by the stats on those columns. What kind of index do you have on graph_id?

Comment: I have a GIST index on `graph_id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85844/discussion-between-novotmike-and-john-powell).

Comment: am I getting that right, you are indexing only those lines that you query, by id? that kind of defeats the purpose of an index...create a spatial index on the whole table for all tables in question. then run `VACUUM ANALYZE <that_table>;` on all tables in question.

Comment: okay, now I see what you are doing, I didn't realize graph_id covers multiple geometries. still try with `VACUUM ANALYZE <table>;` to update the table stats

Comment: @ThingumaBob When I tested I used `VACUUM ANALYZE <table>`. There was not much difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with a large amount of spatial data, it is advisable to tunr Postgresql for PostGIS.  This can make a dramatic difference to performance and may be a contributing factor in your case.

Another performance enhancer that works alonside indexes is clustering.  Eseentially, clustering moves features that are spatially near each other to be physically near each other on the disk (reducing I/O read/write time and disk thrashing).

Tuning Postgresql for spatial is more of an art than a science and depends a lot on your machine's CPU and RAM but I can give you some pointers:

- Boundless uses Postgis and [here](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/dataadmin/pgDBAdmin/tuning.html) are their settings [*a very good place to start!*]
- See here for [hints](https://postgis.net/docs/performance_tips.html) and tips on tuning Postgres and clustering.
- [Here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:Species/PostGIS_Tuning) is OSM's take on tuning the performance (aimed at imporving data access for rendering web maps but the principles are good).

Comment: I will look into it. I have played around with my queries and am at the point where the actual aggregation (`count` or `group by`) takes longest. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the performance of those operations?